# Why does my Python logger not report to Sentry?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sentry

What is the best way to implement **sentry** logging with **breadcrumb** for a **python flask** project.

```py
sentry_logging = LoggingIntegration(
    level=logging.INFO,        # Capture info and above as breadcrumbs
    event_level=logging.ERROR  # Send errors as events
)
```

I have tried with `Logging.info` to get the **breadcrumb** but it logs for **warning**.

Answer (score 1):

Your *logger* likely has set the level to WARNING.

```
mylogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

By the way, you do not have to configure the logging integration explicitly as the levels you're configuring the SDK with are the default already.